# How to get checkbox value from database in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is what I have so far.

```
//Getting access value from the AccessTable

SqlCommand cmadAccess;
string strAccess;
strAccess = "select * from AccessTable where Email='" +
    EmailTextBox.Text.Trim() + "'";
cmadAccess = new SqlCommand(strAccess, conn);
SqlDataReader readAccess = cmadAccess.ExecuteReader();
if (readAccess.Read()) {
    //here I am trying to display data from the database to the checkbox but it does not work.
}
```

These are two examples of what I have tried:

```
TechnitianCheckBox.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(readAccess["ClientTechnitian"]);

TechnitianCheckBox.Checked = readAccess["ClientTechnitian"].ToString();
```

Can anyone indicate the correct way to do this?

Comment: Use parameterized queries, you're looking for injection attacks.

Comment: What is the type of the column `ClientTechnitian` on your table?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? TechnitianCheckBox never ends up checked as you would expect? You get an error?

Comment: As mentioned by @FelipeOriani we also need to know the type of ClientTechnitian. If it's a 'bit' then it should covert quite happily to a bool, but if not then you will probably need to do some jiggery-pokery to check the checkbox or not.

Comment: have you heard about SQL Injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `GetOrdinal(...)` on your reader.

```
TechnitianCheckBox.Checked = readAccess.GetBoolean(readAccess.GetOrdinal("ClientTechnitian"));
```